# How to plot probability density function in R?

Tags: r, plot

I'm attempting to plot a probability density function with an x restriction from -1 to 0, and 0 to 1 so I'm making two plots:

```
x1 = seq(-1, 0, 0.01)
x2 = seq(0, 1, 0.01)

eq1 = function(x) {(1+x)^2}
eq2 = function(x) {(1+x)^3}

plot(x1, eq1, col="red")
par(new = TRUE)
plot(x2, eq2, type = "l", col = "green")
```

However, I get the following error:

> Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 'x' and 'y' lengths
>   differ.

I'm not sure what's up.

Comment: You could replace `eq1 = function(x){(1+x)^2}` by `eq1 <- (1+x1)^2`. The point is to plot vectors against vectors, not vectors against functions. You could also look into `curve()` for your plotting needs.

Comment: @JohnColeman yeah seems like I should, I just use `=` due to a programming background

Comment: @compsciman `=` vs `<-` is mostly just a matter of taste. That isn't the issue here. `eq1 <- (1+x1)^2` doesn't define a function at all. It defines a vector of corresponding `y` values. Using `y1 <- (1+x1)^2` would make that even clearer.

Comment: or `plot(x1, eq1(x1))`

Answer (score 2):

As was pointed out in the comments, the second argument to `plot()` (i.e. `y`) must be a vector:

```
x1 = seq(-1, 0, 0.01)
x2 = seq(0, 1, 0.01)

eq1 = function(x) {(1+x)^2}
eq2 = function(x) {(1+x)^3}

plot(x1, eq1(x1), col="red")
par(new = TRUE)
plot(x2, eq2(x2), type = "l", col = "green")
```

Comment: I get an `attempt to apply non-function` for this